# Jquery onchange for input type dont work?

Tags: jquery

I have a question for onchange and onblur
as i learnt from internet that the onblur will be called when the focus is lost, while the on change will be called when a value is chaged.

for my html input type i was using onblur that was working as desired, but later i realized that a ajax request should be called only when really there is a change in input box value.
So i changed it to onchange function but it is working same as the onBlur what is the reason could some body help me with this.

Comment: Share some code and which browser?

Comment: I think [THIS](http://jsbin.com/awopus/4/edit) is what you thinking about :)

Comment: onchange work well with select's....you should use keypress which is meant for text input types...

Comment: check this link http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onchange

Answer (score 0):

`onchange` is called on blur for `HTML` `input` elements but only if value has changed. `onblur` is called every time the input element loses focus.

Comment: yes true you are but in my case though if i do not change the value the onCange is called